# how can i add a reset password function to my code to

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**My flutter** link on github: https://github.com/SpeedyTiger/flutter-app1

That's the link of my app over here, hope that anyone can help me to add a function to the reset password button that works on my firebase.

I have seen this link over here: https://www.back4app.com/docs/flutter/parse-sdk/users/flutter-reset-password

but i didn't understand it.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly you didn't understand?

Comment: like do i make a new dart file and put it in and link it with my code or i just put it in my login file and put it in the forget password line..? hope you can help me.!

Comment: Btw you got my question right like what is the goal of it yeah..?

Comment: @LuisUtrera can u help me get to my goal and get the function of the reset password work?__ if u dont mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, in your controller add this function

```
  Future<void> resetPassword({required String email}) async {
    try {
      return await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e); // showError(title: '...', error: e);
    }
  }
```

and replace `print(e)` with `Get.snackbar(...)`.

Since you're reusing the `Get.snackbar(...)` multiple times, I recommend that you refactor it out to it's own function with 2 parameters one for the title and the other for the error shown in the comment to keep your code clean.

To use in the widget:

```
          Button(
            isEnabled: controller.isValidEmail.value,
            height: 55.0,
            text: 'Reset Password',
            child: auth.isReseting.value ? const PAIndicator() : null,
            onTap: () async => await Services.auth.resetPassword(email: email),
          ),
```

Comment: @Mhamed Mohamed thx for your answer but could u be more specific about it all I've understood is to put this code in my authcontroller and change the **Print (e) code** with the **Get.snackbar(..)** but when i did that I've got an error that i would like to show you so lets complete the conversation in chat

Comment: I added a sample code to use, I have a custom Button widget where the user can click to request a password reset, the user will then get an email where he will have a link to reset the pass in the browser and will be able to login with the new password in your app.

Comment: All you have to do is show a button for the user to tap on and firebase will handle the rest.

Comment: well https://github.com/SpeedyTiger/flutter-app1 this is the link of my code can u show me what u mean cuz i didn't get ur point and I'm sorry for wasting your time

Comment: can u see my code i sent you the github link up take a look of it and try to edit the thing us said please because when i tried to edit the code gave me error and i thing it was a wrong place or something to put it in.  Hope u edit it and send me a feedback( your github link so i can check it out again)

Comment: In your login_page.dart file, lines 176-204, where you have a "Sign In" GestureDetector, make another one but call it "Forgot Password" either underneath it or wherever you want, then instead of `AuthController.instance.login(emailController.text.trim(), passwordController.text.trim());` do `AuthController.instance.resetPassword(email: emailController.text.trim());` and that's it on your end.

Comment: hold on please stay with me while i try that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242926/discussion-between-mohamed-mohamed-and-speedy12).